# Setter with Abstract Class

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to call a setter method that's in an abstract class from another class. Here's what I have:

```
public abstract class Media {
private String loanedTo;
    public String getLoanedTo() {
        return loanedTo;
    }
    public void setLoanedTo(String loanedTo) {
        this.loanedTo = loanedTo;
    }
    private Date dueOn;
    public Date getDueOn() {
        return dueOn;
    }
    public void setDueOn(Date dueOn) {
        this.dueOn = dueOn;
    }
}

public class Library {
public void loan(Loanable item, String name){
        Calendar calcDueDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        calcDueDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, item.getDaysToLoan());
        dueOn = calcDueDate.getTime();
        loanedTo = name;
    }
}
```

How can I set the dueOn and loanedTo variables from Library that doesn't extend Media which can't be instantiated?  I couldn't find an answer when I searched. Just beginning to learn this stuff.

Comment: Just FYI, `Calendar` is an `abstract` class. You need an object of parent type `Media`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tried to instantiate the abstract Media class, you would fail (because you can't instantiate abstract classes).

If you had a concrete class, say `Book`, and had it `extends Media`, then you could invoke `book.setLoanedTo("Bob")` and `book.setDueOn(someJavaDate)`.

Comment: Thanks. Now it makes sense. Just needed that little hint to help me figure it out.

Comment: YW. Dirk's answer has the whole Book declaration. You don't actually need anything else. If your Library lent CDs, then you could write `public class CD extends Media {}` and have an entirely new class. Then in your Main method, you could say `Book book = new Book();` or `CD myCD = new CD();`

Answer (score 1):

well, you have to make a concrete class like

```
public class Book extends Media {
}
```

If you never have a concrete subclass of an abstract class, then your abstract class can never be used.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some misconceptions in play here.

1. First, your "Abstract" class really is not abstract (there are no unimplemented method signatures).
2. Your Library Class will, one way or another, need to reference an object of a class that extends Media

Check back to the problem you are asked to solve and make sure you are not intended to implement Library as a class that extends Media.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 public abstract class Media {
            private String loanedTo;
            public String getLoanedTo() {
                return loanedTo;
            }
            public void setLoanedTo(String loanedTo) {
                this.loanedTo = loanedTo;
            }
            private Date dueOn;
            public Date getDueOn() {
                return dueOn;
            }
            public void setDueOn(Date dueOn) {
                this.dueOn = dueOn;
            }
        }
        public class ConcreteMedia extends Media {
            private String loanedTo;
            public String getLoanedTo() {
                return loanedTo;
            }
            public void setLoanedTo(String loanedTo) {
                this.loanedTo = loanedTo;
            }
            private Date dueOn;
            public Date getDueOn() {
                return dueOn;
            }
            public void setDueOn(Date dueOn) {
                this.dueOn = dueOn;
            }
        }

        public class Library {
            public void loan(Loanable item, String name){
                Calendar calcDueDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                calcDueDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, item.getDaysToLoan());
                Media concrete = new ConcreteMedia();
                dueOn = concrete.setDueOn(calcDueDate.getTime());
                loanedTo = concrete.SetLoanedTo(name);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your Library.loan method's Item param needs to have the methods you've implemented in abstract Media. Create an interface Loanable with the method declarations. You can have Media implement the interface and remain abstract if you want.

```
public interface Loanable {
   String getLoanedTo();
   void setLoanedTo(String loanedTo);
   Date getDueOn();
   void setDueOn();
}


public abstract class Media implements Loanable {
   private String loanedTo;
   public String getLoanedTo() {
      return loanedTo;
   }
   public void setLoanedTo(String loanedTo) {
      this.loanedTo = loanedTo;
   }
   private Date dueOn;
   public Date getDueOn() {
      return dueOn;
   }
   public void setDueOn(Date dueOn) {
      this.dueOn = dueOn;
   }
}


public class Library {
   public void loan(Loanable item, String name){
      Calendar calcDueDate = Calendar.getInstance();
      calcDueDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, item.getDaysToLoan());
      dueOn = calcDueDate.getTime();
      loanedTo = name;
      item.setDueOn(dueOn);
      item.setLoanedTo(loanedTo);
}
```